# Whats app last seen status not visible

Tags: ios

I have a friend on what's app I cannot only see his last seen status, I was able to see it & since a week now I cant see his last seen status. Although I can see when he is online. Message is send me are delivered as I see the double check mark, so don't think he has blocked me, but not sure why I cant view his last status, I can see my other friends status, but not his????

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp new update has the setting to hide last seen time stamp like iphone users. In `settings-> Account-> Privacy` you can hide last seen time stamp. If you choose to hide the last seen time stamp then you will not be able to see the others last seen time stamp.

Comment: I see, but then when you send them messages they are still able to view it correct???

Comment: Yes they can see. It is only to hide last seen time stamp

Answer (score 1):

No he probably hasn't blocked you. It is the new feature of Whatsapp.There's an option in privacy settings to limit the "last seen" to either no one or only to contacts in your phonebook. When you select either of the two your last seen is visible to only those people. Though the "Online" status is visible when you are online. And massages can be sent and received until blocked.